# RTP/RTSP Live Streaming Display on a web page

Tags: html, streaming, h.264, rtsp, mpeg-4

What is the best solution to display multiple live streams from a surveillance camera (so low latency is a requirement) in a web application (VideoWall-like)?

Personally I'm thinking about two possible solutions, but I can't choose between them:
1) Develop a custom Firefox plugin that uses ffmpeg to acquire and decode the video streams
2) Rely on HTML5 inserting a layer between the cameras and the web application that transcodes/restreams the video streams (probably using http live streaming)

The requirements are compatibility with H.264 over RTSP and Mpeg-4 over RTP and, of course, low latency and no loss on video quality.

Thanks
Andrea